Consistency of IV Estimator
I have a quick question about the proof of the consistency of the IV estimator. I following the Davidson and MacKinnon (1st ed.) text where, as one of their assumptions, they state the following equation:
$$
\text{plim}_{n \to \infty} (n^{-1} \mathbf{Z'u})=\text{lim}_{n \to \infty} (n^{-1}E( \mathbf{Z'u}))=0
$$
My question is, how can we show that the second term implies the first term? Typically, we assume that the instrument is uncorrelated with the error term so what the second term says makes sense to me. But how do we use that to show that $n^{-1} \mathbf{Z'u}$ converges in probability to zero?
My initial thought was that had to with convergence in mean:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} (n^{-1}E( \mathbf{|Z'u-0|}))
$$
Since convergence in mean or mean squared implies convergence in probability, this argument would work. But in the equation above there is no absolute value used and, of course, $\mathbf{Z'u}$ need not be positive.
It could be the case that, in general, one does not imply the other. But then how would one go from lack of correlation to convergence in probability? Here my thought was to simply use Chebyshev's inequality, but obtaining the variance of $n^{-1} \mathbf{Z'u}$ is not easy (and to get anywhere probably requires some sort of mean independence assumption). This is not done in the book which makes me thing I have missed something.

Note that $\frac{1}{n} (Z' u)_j = \frac{1}{n} (\sum_{i=1}^n Z_{i, j} u_i)_j$ is an average. If the rows $(Z_{i, \cdot}, u_i)$ are independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.), the average converges in probability to the expectation $\mathbb{E}[Z_{1, j} u_1]$ by the (weak) law of large numbers.

Alright, so I was just missing something spectacularly simple!
